# How to convert String data type to array when importing CSV file to mongodb

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am importing CSV file to my MongoDB database directly. Here it ask the datatype of field you want. But I want **Array** Datatype which is not mentioned in thier list as shown in below screenshot

[image]

while after importing to database in default formate(String) I can modify datatype of individual document. But can not work for me as database has thousands of documents.

So How can I change datatype of field of imported csv data in mongodb compass

Comment: MongoDB works also with billions of documents, why do you think a few thousand are not possible?

Comment: Yes you are right, but here i have to modify individually. How to change data type of a field in bulk. I am not talking about number of documents but talking about changing the data type if  data imported externally

Comment: It should be possible with a single aggregation pipeline. Please show us some sample data and expected result (as **text**, not as screenshot, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) then you should get an answer.